# allow create table for some users, not all

Tags: postgresql

I need to create 2 roles in postgres, a read only role that only has permission to run SELECT queries, and an admin role that has full superuser privileges.

How can I remove "CREATE TABLE" from 1 role, while allowing "CREATE TABLE" on another role?

I'm using "REVOKE CREATE ON SCHEMA public FROM PUBLIC" to revoke create permissions, but this applies to all roles, and I'd like to allow an admin role to still create tables.

Comment: If you truly want only SELECT privileges for a role, I think you might do `REVOKE ALL ON SCHEMA public FROM myrole` and then `GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA public TO myrole`. The docs have examples for both GRANT and REVOKE

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL doesn't have a special `CREATE TABLE` privilege, everybody is always allowed to create tables. Creating tables is restricted by schema permissions: if you grant a role the `CREATE` privilege on a schema, that role can create tables (and other objects) in that schema.

So grant `CREATE` on a schema to the one role and don't grant `CREATE` on any schema to the other role.