# Issue with permissions to databases using "CREATE TABLE AS SELECT"

Tags: mysql, permissions, create-table

I got following case:
User has permissions to CREATE TABLE on database "a", but "b" doesn't, only query.

Why using
CREATE TABLE a.table1 as select from b.tableX
Print error "user doesnt have privilages for CREATE TABLE as select. The required privilages db=tableX"

I'm looking for reasons why i need to have also privilages to second database with createtable and possible path to deal with limited permissions

I have read documentation about statement CREATE TABLE as SELECT but couldn't find the answer

Comment: You need select permission on database b because you are selecting from it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69275607/599164

Comment: Should share code with some formatting